# Collections Sort Issue in Java

Tags: java, date, arraylist, collections

To put it simply, I have a list of weeks `ArrayList<Week>`, each of which contains a list of days `ArrayList<Day>`, each of which contains a Date object within the Day class. In other words, Weeks, have Days, have Dates.

For a problem I have to randomize the `ArrayList<Week>`, which I use Collections.shuffle for and works fine.

I then need to put them back in order, and I attempted this with:

```
public void sortWeeksInDateOrder(final List<Week> weeks) {
Collections.sort(weeks, new Comparator<Week>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(final Week week1, final Week week2) {
        //Return -1 or 1 if first date is before or after second date.
            return week1.getAllDays().get(0).getDate().before((week2.getAllDays().get(0).getDate())) ? -1 : 1;
        }
    });
}
```

However it's not sorting. Am I missing something? The weeks are never the same so I don't need to return a 0, so I thought this solution would work.

Comment: Why are you comparing using only the first day of the week?  How can two weeks be compared against each other?

Comment: Please show us a [mcve].

Comment: All days within the week object will all either before or after all the day objects in the other week object. So: why not? As far as I can see it should always show the earlier week.

Comment: `compare` should also return `0`. Try `week1.getAllDays().get(0).getDate().compareTo(week2.getAllDays().get(0).getDate()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it clean, you should implement `Comparable` interface to Week class and provide implementation details to `compareTo` method saying how you want to compare Weeks.

Therefore, it would be enough to write:

```
Collections.sort(weeks, new Comparator<Week>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(final Week week1, final Week week2) {
            return week1.compareTo(week2);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Ok I tried this with the following compareTo within the Week class:

     public int compareTo(final Week o) {
      return this.getWeekId().compareTo(o.getWeekId());
     }

Week id is simply an int which holds what position in the original order the week was (e.g. from 1 2 3 4 to, say, 3 2 4 1). 

Still isn't working though I'm afraid.

Comment: Could you post for Week class code? What List implementation do you use?

Comment: ArrayList is the type of list. Here is the week object code:

 public int compareTo(final Week o) {
  return this.getWeekId().compareTo(o.getWeekId());
 }

And here is the getWeekid method it refers to:

 public Integer getWeekId() {
  return this.weekId;
 }

Comment: Seems correct. Can you edit your question and post more code of main method where you shuffle and sort the List?

Comment: Turns out I call the randomize method elsewhere for a different reason, and didn't call the sort afterwards. I'll mark your answer as correct since it's a better approach regardless. Thank you for your time!